# Swagger UI does not load CSS

Tags: c#, azure, swagger-ui, swashbuckle, asp.net-core-2.1

Swagger UI only displays the html, seemingly with no CSS.
This is a ASP.Net Core 2.1 project using the SwashBuckle Nuget package version 2.5.0.

Looks like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbEyY.png

Chrome gives a warning:
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type application/xml: "https://####.servicebus.windows.net/hc2/swagger/swagger-ui.css".

The code to enable Swagger and Swagger UI:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });
        });
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
        });

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

I have tried to inline CSS with `c.InjectStylesheet("/swagger/theme-material.css");` but I get the same result, and another warning like above.
Also tried Downgrading SwashBuckle to 2.4.0

EDIT: It works when using localhost instead of azure-relay-aspnetserver, no idea why but the Chrome warning on CSS disappears

Comment: If it works fine in your localhost, then this is an issue with your Azure setup, have you tried to test deploying to just a WebApp instead of a Relay?

Comment: I guess Relay services is not something I can deploy files to

Comment: You certainly can! but there might be some additional setup to get everything working as it should, maybe you should create a minimal example reproducing the issue and contact Microsoft for support.